# Does nexus 3.0 & above supports Rest call?

Tags: nexus

My Platform: Linux, Repos/Artifacts: Non-Maven. Scripting: only Python,Curl.

Question::
  For my company, I need specific information like,

1. Does Nexus 3.0 & above support rest calls (OSS & PRO)? if Yes, then how?
2. I need to access md5,sha1 of artifacts.using any way, but Rest is better.How can I perform this?
3. Does `/nexus/service/local/`,`/nexus/internal/`,`/nexus/service/siesta/` endpoints have stopped working?
   because 
   https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-presentations/blob/master/labs/rest-api-scripting/rest-api-examples.sh

None of this is working for me.